# Multiple Domain Routing

Tags: php, apache, dns, routes

I want different domains to route to sub-directories on the same server.

Example:

If my Apache root is /var/www/ - I want example1.com to route to /var/www/example1/ - and example2.com to route to var/www/example2/.

Do I need to configure Apache ? Or should I write a PHP script in /var/www/index.php that routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to your Apache configuration file, possibly in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example1"
  ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
  <Directory "/var/www/example1">
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example2"
  ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
  <Directory "/var/www/example2">
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

More information at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/